# Need assistance displaying image in UIScrollView like iOS photo app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview, autolayout

I am trying to display image in my app like `photo app of iOS`

here is what I am doing

1. I drag drop the `UIScrollView` in Xcode and set its `NSLayoutConstraint` `leading`, `trailing`, `top`, `bottom`

[image]

2. Inside `scroll view` drag drop the `UIImageView` and set its `NSLayoutConstraint` `leading`, `trailing`, `top`, `bottom`, `equal width to main view` and `equal height to main view`, And created the `IBOutlets` to `width and height`.

[image]

3. Make my controller `UIScrollViewDelegate` delegate.

> ```
> - (void)viewDidLoad {
>     [super viewDidLoad];
>
>     self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale=0.3;
>     self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale=6.0;
>
>     UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.jpg"];
>
>     self.iVW.constant = img.size.width;
>     self.iVH.constant = img.size.height;
>
>     self.imageView.image = img;
> }
>
> - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
>     [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
>     // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
> }
>
> - (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
> {
>     return self.imageView;
> }
> ```

b.jpg is 11000 x 5000

here is my result at full zoom out :(

[image]

and desire result which is from iOS photo app

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can used this library , it support scrolling , zoom and sharing also

https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser

Comment: thank you for the link, but can you tell me how I can achieve it.